# Проверка на тип файла при загрузке

Tags: javascript, php, fileupload, загрузка

У нас есть простая форма , кнопка выбора нескольких изображений и кнопка загрузки их!

```js
var files;

// Вешаем функцию на событие
// Получим данные файлов и добавим их в переменную
$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
 files = this.files;
});


// Вешаем функцию ан событие click и отправляем AJAX запрос с данными файлов
$('.submit.button').click(function( event ){
 event.stopPropagation(); // Остановка происходящего
 event.preventDefault();  // Полная остановка происходящего

 // Содадим данные формы и добавим в них данные файлов из files
 var data = new FormData();
 $.each( files, function( key, value ){
  data.append( key, value );
 });

 // Отправляем запрос
 $.ajax({
  url: './submit.php?uploadfiles',
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  processData: false, // Не обрабатываем файлы (Don't process the files)
  contentType: false, // Так jQuery скажет серверу что это строковой запрос
  success: function( respond, textStatus, jqXHR ){
   // Если все ОК
   if( typeof respond.error === 'undefined' ){
    // Файлы успешно загружены, делаем что нибудь здесь

    console.log( respond );
    // выведем пути к загруженным файлам в блок '.ajax-respond'
    var files_path = respond.files;
    var html = '';
    $.each( files_path, function( key, val ){ html += val +'<br>'; } )
    $('.ajax-respond').html( html );
   }
   else{
    console.log('ОШИБКИ ОТВЕТА сервера: ' + respond.error );
   }
  },
  error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
   console.log('ОШИБКИ AJAX запроса: ' + textStatus );
  }
 });
 
});

//PHP
<?php

// Переменная ответа
$data = array();

echo json_encode($data);
if( isset( $_GET['uploadfiles'] ) ){  
    $error = false;
    $files = array();

    $uploaddir = './uploads/'; // . - текущая папка где находится submit.php
 
 // Создадим папку если её нет
 if( ! is_dir( $uploaddir ) ) mkdir( $uploaddir, 0777 );

 // переместим файлы из временной директории в указанную
 foreach( $_FILES as $file ){
        if( move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . basename($file['name']) ) ){
            $files[] = realpath( $uploaddir . $file['name'] );
        }
        else{
            $error = true;
        }
    }
 
    $data = $error ? array('error' => 'Ошибка загрузки файлов.') : array('files' => $files );
 
 echo json_encode( $data );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="file" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*">
  <a href="#" class="submit button">Загрузить файлы</a>
  <div class="ajax-respond"></div>
 </div>
```

Никак не могу добавить проверку на тип файла ( надо именно картинки) и сделать изменения имени файла.

Comment: в массиве $_FILES у каждого файла есть ключ "type" - попробуйте использовать его для проверки типа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тип файла нам важен с точки зрения веб-сервера, поскольку именно веб-сервер будет решать, как использовать данный файл. А веб-сервер будет это решать по расширению.

Следовательно, надо всего лишь получить расширение имени файла и проверить его наличие в массиве разрешенных значений

```
$allowedExts = array('png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif');
$ext = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if( !in_array($ext, $allowedExts) )
{
    $error = ['error' => 'invalid image format'];
}
```

Имя файла надо изменить на случайное. Я для этих целей предпочитаю md5 от содержимого файла - так можно будет заодно избежать дублей.

```
$name = md5_file($file['tmp_name']).".$ext";
```

Comment: Спасибо сделал,все работает